# @Binding contained within UIViewControllerRepresentable does not get updated

Tags: swiftui

I have a `UIHostingController` contained in a `UIViewControllerRepresentable` that holds a reference to a binding. When the binding changes, `updateUIViewController` is called, but the underlying view is not automatically re-rendered. How can I signal to the embedded  `UIHostingController` that it needs to update its content?

Following is a simplified version of the scenario. Note that when the stepper changes, the first `Text` automatically updates, but the text contained within the `PassthroughView` `UIViewControllerRepresentable` does not automatically see its content get re-rendered.

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var number = 99

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Stepper("Stepper", value: $number)
            Text("Direct Value: \(number)")
            PassthroughView {
                Text("Passthrough Value: \(number)")
            }
            Spacer()
        }.font(.headline)
    }
}

struct PassthroughView<V: View> : UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    typealias UIViewControllerType = UIHostingController<V>
    let content: V

    init(@ViewBuilder _ content: () -> V) {
        self.content = content()
    }

    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<PassthroughView<V>>) -> UIViewControllerType {
        UIViewControllerType(rootView: content)
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ controller: UIViewControllerType, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<PassthroughView<V>>) {
        // this is called when the binding changes;
        // how to tell the UIHostingController to re-render?
    }
}
```

Comment: do this in `updateUIViewController()`: `controller.rootView = content`

Answer (score 4):

The following code will work as desired:

I am not sure if it is good practice since I am not very familiar with UIKit.

```
struct PassthroughView<V: View> : UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    typealias UIViewControllerType = UIHostingController<V>
    let content: V

    init(@ViewBuilder _ content: () -> V) {
        self.content = content()
    }

    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<PassthroughView<V>>) -> UIViewControllerType {
        UIViewControllerType(rootView: content)
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ controller: UIViewControllerType, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<PassthroughView<V>>) {
        // this is called when the binding changes;
        // how to tell the UIHostingController to re-render?
        controller.rootView = content
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {

    @State var number = 99

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Stepper("Stepper", value: $number)
            Text("Direct Value: \(number)")
            PassthroughView {
                Text("Passthrough Value: \(number)")
            }
            Spacer()
        }.font(.headline)
    }

}
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: That works! I wonder what the performance hit is for re-assigning the `rootView`? Will it make a whole new `UIView` hierarchy for the re-assigned content?

Comment: I don‘t know to be honest! This is not called very often unless the design of the states isn’t done properly... or maybe it depends on the size of the view you assign...